# How to decrease memory usage and make code executed faster than 2s?

Tags: c++

My task is:

Implement a binary search on an array of numbers sorted in non-decreasing order.
It is forbidden to use ready-made binary search functions from standard libraries.

The first line contains an integer n — the number of numbers in the array 1 <= n <= 3*10^5. The second line contains n numbers of the array separated by a space. All numbers are integers and belong to the interval from -2^31 to 2^31 inclusive. The numbers in the array are sorted in non-decreasing order. The third line contains an integer k — the number of requests 1 <= k <= 3*10^5. The fourth line contains k space-separated integers-requests from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1 inclusive.

For each query number x on a separate line print numbers **b**, **l** and **r** separated by a space, where:

- **b** is equal to 1 if x is present in the array, or 0 otherwise;
- **l** is the index of the first element greater than or equal to x;
- **r** is the index of the first element greater than x.

Array elements are numbered with indices from 0 to n-1. If there are no suitable elements in the array, we will agree that the returned value will be equal to n.

Input example:

```
1
1
3
0 1 2
```

Output for the input above must be:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
```

[Here is](https://replit.com/@EmilySeville7cfg/binary-search-zhwdAW4Aj2#main.cpp) my code for the task above:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using string = std::string;
using stringstream = std::stringstream;
template <typename T> using vector = std::vector<T>;

int string_to_int(stringstream& stream, const string &value) {
  int result;
  stream << value;
  stream >> result;
  stream.clear();
  return result;
}

template <typename T> int binary_search(const vector<T> &source, int item) {
  int low = 0;
  int high = source.size() - 1;

  while (low <= high) {
    int middle_index = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int middle = source[middle_index];
    if (middle == item)
      return middle_index;
    if (item < middle)
      high = middle_index - 1;
    else
      low = middle_index + 1;
  }

  return source.size();
}

void split_string_to_words(const string &source, vector<string> &words) {
  string temp;
  words.reserve(100);

  for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); ++i) {
    if (source[i] == ' ') {
      words.push_back(std::move(temp));
      temp.clear();
    } else
      temp.push_back(source[i]);
  }

  words.push_back(temp);
}

int main() {
  stringstream stream;
  
  string line;
  
  getline(std::cin, line);
  int item_count = string_to_int(stream, line);

  getline(std::cin, line);
  vector<string> string_items;
  split_string_to_words(line, string_items);
  
  vector<int> items(item_count);
  std::transform(string_items.begin(), string_items.end(), items.begin(),
            [&](string number) { return string_to_int(stream, number); });

  getline(std::cin, line);
  int search_item_count = string_to_int(stream, line);

  getline(std::cin, line);
  vector<string> search_string_items;
  split_string_to_words(line, search_string_items);

  vector<int> search_items(search_item_count);
  std::transform(search_string_items.begin(), search_string_items.end(),
            search_items.begin(),
            [&](string number) { return string_to_int(stream, number); });

  for (auto item : search_items) {
    int index = binary_search(items, item);
    std::cout << (1 - (index == items.size())) << " ";

    int l = 0;
    while (l < items.size() && items[l] < item)
      l++;

    int r = l;
    while (r < items.size() && items[r] <= item)
      r++;

    std::cout << l << " " << r << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I don't know how to speed up my code. It exceeds 2s on some test cases (but the input data is not shown in the [iRunner2](https://acm.bsu.by/)).

Note that stoi doesn't work in iRunner2.

Comment: Shorthand for `using string = std::string;` is `using std::string;`.

Comment: From what I have seen, most exercises on so-called "competition" and "judge" sites are solved either by what's known as *dynamic programming*, which is a "trick" where you cache and save results of previous calculations so you don't have to do them again. *Or* the trick is to know a  mathematical formula or an algorithm that lowers the number of loops, preferably to zero. Brute force or naive solutions never really work, except for the simplest test-cases.

Comment: Can you explain why you search for `l` *from the start of the array* instead of starting from `index`? You know that the array is sorted in non-decreasing order, so `l` and `r` must by definition be to the right of `index` (or equal to `index` if it is the last element)

Comment: It also helps to not perform unnecessary operations in your code. Like calling `temp.clear()` after you moved the string away from `temp` (where hopefully the string should already *be* clear). ;)

Comment: This sounds like a great time to learn how to profile your code

Comment: For large k it might make sense to sort the requests and use each result to reduce the next search space.

Comment: The code beeing for a competition site or an on line judge, I'd just skip all the input sanity checks and extract `std::int32_t`s using `operator>>`. Focus your attention to the `binary_search` function and format the output exactly as requested.

Comment: @Botje Please note that OP's implementation, unlike `std::lower_bound`, doesn't always returns the *first* element greater or equal to `item`, so that they might need to search to left too, or change the algorithm.